# Batch file to list files and folders in a simple format

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that recursively list folders and their files (with dates) to a text file. I've found several online, like this one

```
echo off
for /d %%a in (*.*) do dir "%%a" >> Report.txt
```

But none in the simple format that I need. The batch file would be run from the top search directory. I'd like to full path to the search folder listed at the top, followed by the folder and subfolder names, even if they're empty, without their paths, each followed by their files accompanied with a time stamp. So, something like this:

```
FullPathToTopFolder 
    FolderName1
        DateStamp   FileName1.txt      
        DateStamp   FileName2.txt      
        DateStamp   FileName3.txt      
    FolderName2
        DateStamp   FileName4.txt      
        DateStamp   FileName5.txt       
    FolderName3
        DateStamp   FileName6.txt      
    FolderName3
        /SubFolderName1
            DateStamp   FileName7.txt      
            DateStamp   FileName8.txt      
    FolderName4 
        /SubFolderName2
        /SubFolderName3
        /SubFolderName4
            DateStamp   FileName9.txt      
            DateStamp   FileName10.txt
```

Comment: This looks like Windows/MS-DOS. If so, could you tag the question as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script allows the top folder to be specified as the first parameter. If not provided, then uses the current directory as the top folder.

*Edited to redirect output to a file*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1
set "tab=    "
set "indent="
call :run >report.txt
exit /b

:run
for %%F in (.) do echo %%~fF

:listFolder
setlocal
set "indent=%indent%%tab%"
for %%F in (*) do echo %indent%%%~tF   %%F
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  echo %indent%.\%%F
  pushd "%%F"
  call :listFolder
  popd
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Awesome! This does exactly what I need and worked flawlessly. Many thanks.

Comment: I need one tweak -- for the script to redirect to file, rather than the screen. If I simply put ">> Report.txt" after each echo, it spreads Report.txt across subfolders due to the recursion. I could run this batch file from another batch file and redirect it, but I'd rather have it self-contained.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys - You could simply redirect output when you call the script. Or you could include the path when you redirect with `>>"reportPath\report.txt"` at each echo. Or you can encapsulate the code in a subroutine and redirect when you call it, as I have done in my edited answer. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That lets others know the question has been answered, awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer per question can be accepted.

Comment: Many thanks. Thanks too for educating me on accepting answers.

Comment: After reading your explanation, I took your advice and reverted back to you original version and redirect the output when I call the script. It's working great. The only snag is it only sorts files and folders alphabetically when the path being searched is on my local machine. When the path is on our office server (script on my local machine) the folders and files aren't listed alphabetically?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys: That actually could make a good *new* question. :)

Comment: @AndriyM Yes! Thanks. I just posted it.