# count folders and subfolders with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking to create a batch file that when given a pathway, it will count all the folders and sub folders within it.  So far I am only able to gather the number of folders within the 1st level of the pathway.  I will then pipe it to a text file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad %folder%^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
echo %count% folder(s^)>> !output!
```

Am I close to getting what I want? What do I need to tweek?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `/s` to include all subfolders:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad %folder%^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
echo %count% folder(s^)>> !output!
```

Comment: Thanks! My simple brain missed that. I should have known it would be something simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

A small edit of this answer: [Batch file to list files and folders in a simple format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917348/batch-file-to-list-files-and-folders-in-a-simple-format)

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1
set "tab=    "
set "indent="
call :listFolder >report.txt
exit /b

:listFolder
setlocal
set "indent=%indent%%tab%"
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  echo %indent%.\%%F
  pushd "%%F"
  call :listFolder
  popd
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem.

```
if exist "File Count" del "File Count"
dir "%~d1%~p1\*.*" /b /s >> "File Count"
find /c "." "File Count"
```

First we check to see if a file exists, and if so, delete it.  Then we get a list of files and dump that to our file.  then run FIND on the file.  FIND will handily give us a big label, so the name of the file might as well be something attractive and human readable.

I am personally interested in a specific filetype, so I changed *.* into *.jpg but the principle is the same.