# count number of subdirectories within subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm looking to see the maximum number of subdirectories within any subdirectory within a folder. 
I.e.,

```
Folder==>
    SubA==>
        b.xlsx
    SubB==>
        SubB.C==>
           b.c.xlsx
```

Such that this would return (2) as SubB.C is two folders deep.

I've tried

```
set count=
for /d %%a in (U:\*) do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
```

But the recursion is stumping me. I can't get into the second/third/fourth level subdirectories.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what specifically do you have troubles with?

Comment: For counting the folders inside, you can have a solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19709695/4636715). Then, you can find the maximum of them. After those, share what you tried and where it fails etc. Otherwise, it would be a kind of write-code-for-me service :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some kind of recursion for that task. What about a sub-routine that loops through the sub-directories and calls itself for each one? What I mean is the following:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define constants here:
set "_PATH=%~1"   & rem // (path of the root directory to process)
rem // Define global variables here:
set /A "$DEPTH=0" & rem // (variable to determine the greatest depth)

rem // Initialise variables:
set /A "DEEP=0" & rem // (depth of the current directory branch)
rem // Call recursive sub-routine, avoid empty argument:
if defined _PATH (call :SUB "%_PATH%") else (call :SUB ".")
rem // Return found depth:
echo %$DEPTH%
exit /B

:SUB  <root_path>
rem // Loop through all sub-directories of the given one:
for /D %%D in ("%~1\*") do (
    rem // For each sub-directory increment depth counter:
    set /A "DEEP+=1"
    rem // For each sub-directory recursively call the sub-routine:
    call :SUB "%%~fD"
)
rem // Check whether current branch has the deepest directory hierarchy:
if %$DEPTH% lss %DEEP% set /A "$DEPTH=DEEP"
rem // Decrement depth counter before returning from sub-routine:
set /A "DEEP-=1"
exit /B
```

---

Just as an alternative idea, but with a bit worse performance, you could also determine the number of backslashes (`\`) in the resolved paths of all sub-directories, retrieve the greatest number and subtract that number of the root directory from the greatest one, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define constants here:
set "_PATH=%~1"   & rem // (path of the root directory to process)
rem // Define global variables here:
set /A "$DEPTH=0" & rem // (variable to determine the greatest depth)

rem // Change to root directory:
pushd "%_PATH%" || exit /B 1
rem // Resolve root directory:
call :SUB "."
rem // Store total depth of root directory:
set /A "CROOT=$DEPTH, $DEPTH=0"
rem // Process all sub-directories recursicely:
for /D /R %%D in ("*") do (
    rem // Determine greatest depth relative to root:
    call :SUB "%%~fD" -%CROOT%
)
rem // Change back to original directory:
popd
rem // Return found depth:
echo %$DEPTH%
exit /B

:SUB  <val_path>  [<val_offset>]
rem // Resolve provided sub-directory:
set "ITEM=%~f1" & if not defined ITEM set "ITEM=."
rem // Initialise variables, apply count offset:
set "COUNT=%~2" & set /A "COUNT+=0"
rem // Count number of backslashes in provided path:
for %%C in ("%ITEM:\=" "%") do (
    set /A "COUNT+=1"
)
rem // Check whether current branch has the deepest directory hierarchy:
if %$DEPTH% lss %COUNT% set /A "$DEPTH=COUNT"
exit /B
```

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea about performance, *(only an issue with large directory trees)*, but you could maybe try a `PowerShell` based method from your batch file too:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "U:\" 2>Nul || Exit /B
PowerShell -NoL -NoP "GCI .\ -R|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|Select @{Name='FullName';Expression={$_.FullName.Replace($PWD,'')}},@{Name='FolderDepth';Expression={($_.FullName.Split('\').Count)-($PWD.Path.Split('\').Count)}}|Sort -Des FolderDepth|Select -F 1 -Exp FolderDepth"
Pause
```

**Edit** *(to satisfy the requirements in lit's comment)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "U:\" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "MaxLevels="
For /F %%A In ('
    PowerShell -NoL -NoP "GCI .\ -R|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|Select @{Name='FullName';Expression={$_.FullName.Replace($PWD,'')}},@{Name='FolderDepth';Expression={($_.FullName.Split('\').Count)-($PWD.Path.Split('\').Count)}}|Sort -Des FolderDepth|Select -F 1 -Exp FolderDepth"
') Do Set "MaxLevels=%%A"
Set MaxLevels 2>Nul
Pause
```

Comment: Probably should use `-NoLogo -NoProfile` on the PowerShell invocation. The OP will want this in a cmd variable. Does that mean the awkward FOR is required?

Comment: @lit, I did not see a requirement in the OP for a cmd variable to contain such information, only for it to be returned, but have provided an **Edit** to my answer to cover it, _adding also the two `PowerShell` options_.

Answer (score 3):

You can hack [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) (regular expression text processor) to count the number of backslashes in each path. I list the root folder first so that I can subtract that value from the max to get the maximum subfolder depth within the root folder.

```
@echo off
pushd %1
(cd & dir /b /s /ad) | jrepl "\\" "$txt=false;n++" ^
  /JMATCHQ ^
  /JBEG "var n, root, max=0" ^
  /JBEGLN "n=0" ^
  /JENDLN "if (ln==1) root=n; if (n>max) max=n" ^
  /JEND "output.writeLine(max-root)"
popd
```

I used a lot of `^` line continuation to make the code easy to read without horizontal scrolling.

If you want to capture the result in a variable, then the easiest solution is to write the CD and DIR output to a temp file and use the JREPL /RTN option to save the result.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=%temp%\folders.txt"
pushd %1
(cd & dir /b /s /ad) >"%file%"
popd
call jrepl "\\" "$txt=false;n++" /F "%file%" ^
  /JMATCHQ ^
  /JBEG "var n, root, max=0" ^
  /JBEGLN "n=0" ^
  /JENDLN "if (ln==1) root=n; if (n>max) max=n" ^
  /JEND "output.writeLine(max-root)" ^
  /RTN count
del "%file%"
echo %count%
```

On my machine, my code runs about twice as fast as Compo's powershell solution, and *much, much* faster than the aschipfl recursive pure batch solution.

---

Here is a hybrid JScript/batch solution that doesn't require JREPL.BAT

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::--- Batch section within JScript comment that calls the internal JScript ----
@echo off
pushd %1 || exit /b
(cd & dir /b /s /ad) | cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
popd
exit /b

----- End of JScript comment, beginning of normal JScript  ------------------*/
var root=0, max=0, level;
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  level=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().split('\\').length-root;
  if (!root) root=level;
  if (level>max) max=level;
}
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(max);
```

If you want to capture the result in a variable, then you can use a FOR /F loop:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::--- Batch section within JScript comment that calls the internal JScript ----
@echo off
pushd %1 || exit /b
for /f %%A in ('(cd ^& dir /b /s /ad^) ^| cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"') do set depth=%%A
popd
set depth
exit /b

----- End of JScript comment, beginning of normal JScript  ------------------*/
var root=0, max=0, level;
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  level=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().split('\\').length-root;
  if (!root) root=level;
  if (level>max) max=level;
}
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(max);
```

Comment: ...but the time taken to go to the site, download it, unzip it and preferably put it somewhere on `%PATH%` may increase the time somewhat. ;-)

Comment: @Compo - True, though once you have JREPL, it is a mighty handy tool. I've added a self-contained hybrid JScript/batch solution that is a shade faster than the JREPL solution.

Comment: Upvote and +1 for that, it's what you should have posted in the first place. _When you see how simple it is using the underlying language, it makes your tool seem bloated and overcomplicated. More especially when it appears as if you have to be relatively familiar with `jScript`, to be able to formulate the `JREPL` answer too!_

Comment: @Compo - Fair enough. That is why my original answer uses the term "hack JREPL.BAT".